# what is a correct path for macbook webcam

Tags: macos, go, webcam

I am trying to get a stream from MacBook High Sierra webcam, mac does not have **/dev/video0**
is there any way to access MacOS webcam ?
I am programming in golang and I am using **golang.org/x/sys/unix**

Comment: Have a look at this question
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/mac-webcam-get-the-device

Comment: I saw that question, so there is no equivalent to /dev/video0, so is there any other way to access MacOS webcam ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV bindings and get frame from camera.

Have a look at [godoc for go-opencv](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-opencv/go-opencv/opencv#NewCameraCapture)

A short example:

```
index := 0 // example
camera := opencv.NewCameraCapture(index)

if camera.GrabFrame() {
    frame := camera.RetrieveFrame(1)
    img := frame.ToImage()
}
```